# No Series in windows forms & SQL

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms-designer

Hi I am currently developing a stock and sales management system using windows forms (C#) and an SQL Server database. When the user creates a new Purchase Order, I would like the Purchase Order No. to be generated automatically ex; PO0001 (even numbers only without the 'PO' should be fine). Can you help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Identity` property in SQL Server.

You can read about it here -> [SQL Identity property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)

To borrow a definition and an example from that page :

> Creates an identity column in a table. This property is used with the
>   CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE Transact-SQL statements.

Syntax : `IDENTITY [(seed , increment)]`

> *seed* : Is the value that is used for the very first row loaded into
>   the table.
>
> *increment* : Is the incremental value that is added to the identity
>   value of the previous row that was loaded.

You must specify both the seed and increment or neither. If neither is specified, the default is (1,1).

Here 's an example of how you'd use it to create an identity column :

```
CREATE TABLE new_employees
(
 id_num int IDENTITY(1,1),      //This is the identity column
 fname varchar (20),
 minit char(1),
 lname varchar(30)
);
```